# a div element will not fit inside another while using a fluid layout

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a webpage layout and I came across this issue.

```
<div id="pageWrapper">
  <div id="pageHeader">
  </div><!-- end of pageHeader -->

  <div id="navTab">
    <div class="navButtons"></div>
  </div><!-- end of navTab -->
</div><!-- end of wrapper -->
```

and my css looks like

```
#pageWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#pageHeader {
  width:100%;
  height:7%;
  color:#DADADA;
  float:left; 
}

#navTab {
  width:100%;
  height:6%;
  background-color:#000000;
  float:left;
}

.navButtons{
  width:100px;
  height:90%;
  margin:5%;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  float:left;
}

.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create a fluid layout and trying to add `.navButtons` div inside `#navTab` width a margin-top and bottom 5%...but when I give parameters in CSS it will not fit inside the div.. what am I doing wrong here???

Im adding a jsbin link http://jsbin.com/ezeqec/1/edit

Comment: umm, try removing that `margin: 5%` from that `.navButtons`. If you want the horizontal margins, make it `margin: 0 5%;`

Answer (score 1):

umm, try removing that `margin: 5%` from that `.navButtons`. If you want the horizontal margins, make it `margin: 0 5%;`

Else, if you want that vertial margin too, just do this:

```
<div id="navTab">
<div class="navButtons"></div>
<div class="clearFloat"></div> <!-- added this -->
</div><!-- end of navTab -->
```

CSS changes:

```
.navButtons {
    width:100px;
    height:90px; /* in pixels instead of % */
    margin:5%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

#navTab {
        width:100px;
    height:90%; /* this should be in pixels, if you want to give % for navButtons */
    margin:5%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

If you want to give `height` in %, the parent element's height should be fixed. The parent element cannot have `height` in % or `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove statements 'float' everywhere but in navTab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `navTab` to contain it's child `navButtons`, which is floated, you need to add some CSS so force the element to expand. I find the easiest is `overflow:auto`.

The basic problem is that floating an element takes it out of the normal document flow, and so it doesn't get factored into height/width calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Assign .clearfix to your pageWrapper and that should keep your wrapper from collapsing.

```
.clearfix:after {
clear:both;
content:".";
display:block;
font-size:0;
height:0;
visibility:hidden;
}
.clearfix { 
zoom:1; 
}
```

The first part of [this article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) is a good refresher on floating elements but near the back half of the page are some good techniques on keeping your elements from collapsing when all of their child elements are floated.